# How do I determine the boundingRect() of a QGraphicsTextItem based on its contents?

Tags: c++, qt, text, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to subclass some `QGraphicsItem` classes:

for `QGraphicsTextItem` how do I determine the `boundingRect()` and `shape()` ?

I am trying to create a `boundingRect` out of `textWidth()` and... ?

apparently, in the paint(...) I also have to specify the rectangle I must draw in... and I thought I solved it simply by using

```
QRectF TextItem::boundingRect() const
{
    qreal w = textWidth(); qreal h = 1000;  // h = ?
//    QRectF rect(QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect());  // this leads to crash, maybe undefined ?
    QRectF rect(0,0,w,h)
    return rect;
}

void TextItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* /*option*/, QWidget* /*widget*/)
{
    setDefaultTextColor(m_color);
    setPlainText("Hello world");
    QFont f;
    f.setPointSize(200); // calculated
    f.setBold(true);
    painter->setFont(f); // which of this and the next I need...
    setFont(f);          // really seems one of this is not needed
    painter->drawText(QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, this->toPlainText());
}
```

I need to get the `boundingRect()` out of the actual text - is that possible or already implemented ?

Comment: Why can't you use QGraphicsTextItem's implementation? That is, don't override `boundingRect()`. What kind of crash do you get? Did you debug it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. why you are subclassing `QGraphicsTextItem`? I don't see that you are adding any kind of functionality which is not already done in `QGraphicsTextItem`.
2. You have quite nice SO reputation but you ask question like a newbie. First describe what is your primary goal! The way you are trying to solve this is secondary thing!
3. read documentation. It quite good. `boundingRect` has to return smallest possible rectangle which contains whole drawing content of the graphics item. If this value is incorrect you may see some painting artifacts. It is always implemented.
4. it is qiute possible that if you will read documentation of it will turn out that you don't have to subclass anything.

Comment: I have a large number of object types, that all inherit from QGraphicsItem (or a child) and another class, so they work together. I thought I had to implement boundingRect() - for all classes implementing QGraphicsItem, I had to - and the documentation of QGraphicsTextItem only states "Reimplemented from QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()" (so now I realize it means that it is actually implemented).

Comment: As for crash... the program actually freezes after I move the TextItem object to another scene, and I have been trying to troubleshoot but every step passes fine, all values are as expected - so I was trying to fix items that I didn't feel I had control over. (all other item types function fine)

Comment: Thank you for letting me see that I am looking in the wrong place for the problem, and that I don't need to override the boundingRect() - I asked whether it was already implemented, and your point 3. answers my question.